# ASP.NET Core 5 Web API : slow response for the first REST call

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, dotnet-httpclient

My ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API (HTTPS) is running on Windows 7 SP1.

The first `HttpClient` REST call (from a .NET 5.0 client) gets a very slow response, the next call is very fast, after a while (around 2 minutes), the next call is again very slow, and calls after that are very fast again, and so on.

What can cause this strange issue?

Comment: Could you upload a minimal example that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng the problem is resolved by reinstalling Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is resolved by reinstalling Windows

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).